# Is Online Capacity Expansion possible in Windows 7 software raid?

Tags: raid, software-raid

Many low-end raid cards now offer Online Capacity Expansion (OCE) and Online Raid Level Migration (ORLM).  [This explains both.](http://www.highpoint-tech.com/PDF/Expanding_Storage_Capacity-A_Primer.pdf)

Can I do OCE or ORLM on my Windows 7 software RAID to add disks and/or create more space on the logical drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you'll have to backup the array, break it, and then add the disk to the array.

You can only extend simple and spanned dynamic volumes.

https://serverfault.com/questions/18361/expand-windows-server-2008-raid-5-array

Answer (score 0):

You can add new disks to the `Spanned Dynamic Disks` (which is Raid 0) but not to `Stripped Dynamic Disks` (which is a redundant raid version, such as Raid 5)

If you have the Spanned Dynamic Disks, then all you need to do is right click on an empty disk of greater than or equal to size and then `Add Storage` to add a disk to the Windows raid array.  **This does not work for Striped**.

[image]